# Component dependencies & Using life cycle hooks as logic

Tags: angular

**The problem :**

```
  <div class="appContainer">
    <my-cube-container></my-cube-container>
    <my-toolbox></my-toolbox>
  </div>
```

`my-toolbox` calls a service inside its constructor. That `service A` calls another `service B` and set values into that service. `my-cube-container` calls `service B` in its constructor. When `my-cube-container` calls `service B` the values aren't initialized.

**Possible resolution ?:**

- Using life cycle hooks: if one service is called in onNgInit() it will be called after any other service that is used in a component constructor. That however feels a bit wrong and is not explicit.
- Tell angular that a component is dependent of another one. I think this is more explicit, and I would like to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, keep the things the way they are, but move all the calls to your services into `ngInit()` all logic should be inside that method and not on the constructor. That will just make your life harder when it comes to testing. After that you could create an observable for the values on `service B` and make your `<my-cube-container></my-cube-container>` subscribe to that observable, so it gets notified when those values are available.

Another option would be creating a new component to wrap those two components. So this component will be responsible to feed the data to `<my-cube-container>` and  `<my-toolbox>` and would look something like this:

```
<my-wrapper>
  <my-cube-container [values]="serviceBValues"></my-cube-container>
  <my-toolbox (setValues)="setValues($event)"></my-toolbox>
</my-wrapper>
```

And the `ts` code would be something like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-wrapper',
  template: `
    <my-wrapper>
      <my-cube-container [values]="serviceBValues"></my-cube-container>
      <my-toolbox (setValues)="setValues($event)"></my-toolbox>
    </my-wrapper>
  `
})
export class MyWrapperComponent {
  public serviceBValues;

  constructor(private serviceA: ServiceB, private serviceB: ServiceB)

  setValues(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.serviceA(event);
    this.serviceBValues = this.serviceB.getValues(); // I guess they will be available by now, if not use promises or observables
  }
}
```

So `<my-wrapper>` would be responsible for all the logic and your actual components would be more dummy components who only show your data.

Comment: Nice answer but I'll have to disagree. Here is why. For the Observer design, it means that every component in the tree is gonna be initialized before the subscribe callback is gonna be called. That means that there is a first round trip of initialization in my-cube-container and its children that is essentially worthless.This first round trip may also yield errors as  my-cube-container will have uninitialized values (unless I have defaults ones). I hoped for something less "hacky"

Comment: Actually this is the solution for my issue. I still think it's not perfect though